# Query is locking tables, can't kill that process

Tags: mysql, deadlock, database-deadlocks, kill-process

I have a query locking tables in MySQL (using InnoDB):

```
UPDATE table SET status = 2 WHERE status = 3
```

This query caused a deadlock on the table and can't bypass it.

I tried to do:

```
show processlist
```

then kill the process id but i can't seems to kill it

I tried:

```
kill 9588
```

9588 is the process id.

Then I do `show processlist` I still see the same query on the list.

How can I force killing this process and then why would this query cause a dead lock? how can I fix it?

Comment: `kill -9` is an operating system command, not a MySQL command.

Comment: the `UPDATE` will block if it can not get write access to any of the rows with `status=3`.  I would make sure all transactions have commited their changes and you have no oustanding `select for update`

Answer (score 30):

When you run a MySQL instance on RDS and want to kill a thread or a query for some reason, you’ll find you cannot use `KILL` or `mysqladmin kill` because you don’t have a permission to do so.

RDS provides the stored procedures named `mysql.rds_kill` and `mysql.rds_kill_query` which will kill a thread and a query respectively. To kill a thread, first use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to get the list of threads and find the id of the thread you want to kill. Assuming the thread id is 53512, then use

```
CALL mysql.rds_kill(53512)
```

Source:
http://snak.tumblr.com/post/13856391340/killing-a-thread-or-query-of-mysql-running-on-rds

Comment: Official docs on that: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.CommonDBATasks.html

Comment: Snippet for quickly  create  stored procedures   : `Select concat('CALL mysql.rds_kill(',id,');') from information_schema.processlist;`

Answer (score 6):

The `KILL` command requests the query terminate, and the state of the command should show up as `Killed`. There's no way to force-kill something and have it terminate immediately.

As a last resort you can always shut-down and restart your `mysqld` server process.

Comment: The 'last resort' comment is totally unneeded. Would not achieve anything difference, you can only either forcefully terminate the mysqld process or just issue your kill command and wait till it's actually executed.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata I've seen `mysqld` in a state where it's unkillable and will not shut down at all. You may need to hard restart if it won't go peacefully.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, if they're having an issue killing the process already, then issuing a shutdown or restart will not help. You have to forcefully kill or just issue your kill query and wait.

Answer (score 5):

You need to run following command to kill the process.

```
> show processlist;  
> kill query processId;
```

Query parameter specifies that we need to kill query command process.

The syntax for kill process as follows

> KILL [CONNECTION | QUERY] processlist_id

Please [refer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html) this link for more information.

Answer (score 1):

you should try to kill the `mysql/sql service` on you computer first and than tray to kill the the program you are runnen white the query.

hope it will work for you

Comment: okay this killed the query. Thanks  But I am hitting dead locks!

Comment: maybe i could help you with your query if you tell me a little more about your database and what your trying to do. if you didn't solved it jet.

Comment: This answer could be better by providing a sample command to kill mysql.